# Android image sharing app works on my phone but not on anybody else's

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm writing an app that sends images and video from an Android phone to a server. My intent filter looks like this:

```
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
```

The problem is that it works perfectly for me on my Nexus S phone, but if anyone else installs it from the same release package it doesn't appear int their share menu in the gallery app. I'm at a loss here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me (on different devices):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

same for video, just change the mime type. Also if you can get log out from the problematic device, there is a chance you can see the intent details and perhaps get some idea of what's different